# Creating a submodule in a git project

Tags: django, git, version-control, github, git-submodules

I have a Django project and it's currently hosted in GitHub and it's private. I'm looking to move many useful parts of it into an open-source project. I think I need to use a 'submodule' thing, but unfortunately I have no idea how to operate these.

Please can someone help me :)

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> move many useful parts of it into an open-source project.

That means extract one or several directories (and their associated history) into several independant git repositories, each one pushed to a public GitHub repo.

- To extract a sub-directory from a Git repo, see the [`filter-branch` command in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538245/extract-part-of-a-git-repository)
  (also in:

  - "[Howto extract a git subdirectory and make a submodule out of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/howto-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it)"
  - [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)
    )
- to reference those new repositories, reference them in your original private repo to see them again directly from your current Django project: see [true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194).