# How can I add a specific folder from a git repo as a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo and I want to add a submodule to it. Problem is, the submodule exists as a folder inside another repo. Can I add only that folder as a submodule?

Comment: I found a solution in SO that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035895/how-do-i-add-a-submodule-to-a-sub-directory

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you really need to include part of an other repository within the history of your own repo, then the [subtree merge strategy](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) is more adequate than submodules.

> - name the other project "repo1", and fetch.
> - prepare for the later step to record the result as a merge.
> - read "main" branch of repo1 to the subdirectory "repo1".
> - record the merge result.
> - maintain the result with subsequent merges using "subtree"

```bash
$ git remote add -f repo1 /path/to/repo1
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories repo1/main
$ git read-tree --prefix=repo1/ -u repo1/main
$ git commit -m "Merge repo1 as our subdirectory"
$ git pull -s subtree repo1 main
```

But in both case, the full repository is linked to your repo, not just one directory.
And [partial cloning is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial/2587244#2587244).

You could try and [isolate that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538245/extract-part-of-a-git-repository) in its own repository, and then add it as a submodule, but that means its history will be totally separated from the repo its was coming from originally.

The [modern example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65265319/6309) would use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)

```bash
cd /path/to/repo1
git filter-repo --path repo1SubFolder

#Move the files inside repo1SubFolderto the root
git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter repo1SubFolder/

# Go to your new repository, add a remote to the original repository
cd /path/to/repo2
git remote add repo1 /path/to/repo1

# Pull files and history from this branch into repo2 
# (containing only the directory you want to move) .
git pull repo1 main
git remote rm repo1
```

Comment: I found this note in your [subtree merge strategy](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) particularly relevant: `Also, in case you make changes to the other project, it is easier to submit changes if you just use submodules.`

Comment: @DevinRhode 11 years later, I agree. I mostly use submodules these days.

Comment: Links pages tend to disappear much more frequently than you think. it would be nice if you could add the actual example here.

Comment: @AaA Very true. I have included the relevant (and updated) examples in the answer.

Answer (score 48):

I ended up doing this:

1. Create a `submodules` directory.
2. Add the submodule in this directory.
3. Create a symlink to the specific directory inside the submodule.

This way you have default Git submodule behaviour and in your project you only use a subset of the whole submodule.

Comment: hmmm I don't know if this will fly with my Windows developers but we shall try it and tell

Comment: @CaptainMan this works if you install GitBash with the "Enable Symbolic Links" permission!

Comment: Excellent.  Except antora/asciidoctor doesn't support symlinks :(

Answer (score -2):

1. Create new branch
2. Move required files to new branch
3. Add sub module to super repository
4. Checkout sub-module to new branch