# How to clone only a folder from a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to get just a folder from an external github repo to use in my project.

I want my project setup to be like this:

```
-my_project
    -submodule
        -code.py
    -MY_README
    -.git
```

And I have the remote repo named some-submodule with following structure:

```
-submodule
    -code.py
-README
-.gitignore
```

So I just want the submodule folder added to my project.

But I end up with this after

```
git submodule add http://github.com/user/submodule.git submodule
```

```
-my_project
    -submodule
        -submodule
            -code.py
        -README
        -.gitignore
    -MY_README
    -.gitignore
```

I am new to git so I really don't know if it possible using just git. If it is of some help I'm using msysgit on windows.

So, is there anyway that I can get a clean submodule folder in my project from a public repo?

If you're curious of exactly what I'm trying to do I'm trying to take directly from their repos these django plugins [1](http://github.com/adieu/django-dbindexer) [2](http://github.com/adieu/djangotoolbox) to add them to my project.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can I add a specific folder from a git repo as a git submodule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158597/how-can-i-add-a-specific-folder-from-a-git-repo-as-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a git submodule to point to a subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303496/how-to-change-a-git-submodule-to-point-to-a-subfolder)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What you want to do is not feasible because you cannot clone a part of a repository.

See details in duplicate [How to change a git submodule to point to a subfolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303496/how-to-change-a-git-submodule-to-point-to-a-subfolder)

Comment: While, strictly speaking, _cloning_ only parts of a repository is not possible there is **sparse checkout** since Git 1.7 to solve what the OP probably wants. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

Answer (score 9):

If you:

```
git submodule add http://github.com/user/submodule.git
```

directly under `my_project`, you should end up with the desired organization of directories.

From [`git submodule add` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> The optional argument `<path>` is the relative location for the cloned submodule to exist in the superproject.
>   If `<path>` is not given, the "humanish" part of the source repository is used ("repo" for "`/path/to/repo.git`" and "`foo`" for "`host.xz:foo/.git`").

Comment: Awesome! I was following tutorials all the way and I didn't read the manual... I thought that I would end up with README file of the submodule in my own project...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a problem though... it only works if the repo of the submodule has the same name as the folder I want to use but if not ie: repo->django-submodule  folder name->submodule it doesn't work anymore. Let's see if I find some workaround

Comment: I'm sorry man, I tried your solution with one of the repos that was well structured and I thought the problem was already solved... my bad.

Answer (score -4):

just

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

in the root-directory of your project and it should do what you want