# How do I share a folder from one Git repository to another?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have two projects [git repos] that share a database schema, but only one of the projects actually contains the DDL SQL files.  I know I could add the one containing the SQL as a subtree, but that would take over all the code and everything - all I need is the directory with the SQL files, so I can create the schema in the second project for testing using H2.  I'd really rather not try to keep them synched manually [never works] - so I was hoping to simply link the `/sql` folder in project 1 into project 2.

I also cannot create any new repos in Git.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866733/how-to-clone-only-a-folder-from-a-git-submodule). You would need to extract the files that you want to share to a third repository that both existing repos depend on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. [Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Using Git's *submodules*, you can only link the whole repository inside another one. So one way would be to separate the whole `/sql` directory into an individual repository and link it as a submodule into both repositories.

In this case, changes into files of the linked repository will get pushed to the source repository.

### 2. [Subtree](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_subtree_merge)

But there's also a *subtree* which may allow what you need. But I have never used that so you have to try it.

Check for example [this page](https://jrsmith3.github.io/merging-a-subdirectory-from-another-repo-via-git-subtree.html):

```
# Clone the target repo
git clone git@github.com:jclouds/jclouds.git
cd jclouds

# Add the source repository as a remote, and perform the initial fetch.
git remote add -f sourcerepo git@github.com:jclouds/jclouds-labs-openstack.git

# Create a branch based on the source repositories' branch that contains the state you want to copy.
git checkout -b staging-branch sourcerepo/master

# Here's where the two approaches diverge.
# Create a synthetic branch using the commits in `/openstack-glance/` from `sourcerepo`
git subtree split -P openstack-glance -b openstack-glance

# Checkout `master` and add the new `openstack-glance` branch into `/apis/openstack-glance/`. At this point, the desired result will have been achieved.
git checkout master
git subtree add -P apis/openstack-glance openstack-glance

# Clean up by removing the commits from the `openstack-glance` branch and the `sourcerepo` remote.
git branch -D openstack-glance staging-branch
git remote rm sourcerepo
```

In this case, changes to the linked subtree or directory won't get pushed back to the source repository, but that what you need I guess so should be fine.

Comment: This appears to be the same thing I mentioned in the question - this copies the entire project into the other project, not just the folder with the SQL files.

Comment: I don't know which method you're referring to, if the first one, yeah, you're right, I'm mentioning it in the very first sentence. If the second one, it should be possible to link just subdirectory according to that article I linked but as I mentioned, I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Using this method is it possible to keep that directory up to date with the source repo by doing a pull?  Or do you have to repeat this whole process each time?

Comment: @Gandalf Oh, sorry, I really don't have a clue. You have to investigate it. So did you chose the subtree method? But I would love if you can share the results here. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native feature in Git that does what you want. Two "tricks" that come to my mind:

1. As you say you can't create a third repo to store only the shared SQL files, you could create an [orphan branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt) in the repo that already contains the SQL files, move the files there, and use that branch as a submodule in both repos.
2. You could [combine the submodule approach with a sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45688121/1127485) to only checkout the SQL files. However, this still fetches the whole history of the submodule, it's just that no other files than the SQL files will be checked out in your working tree.