# Push commits affecting a given path to a new origin?

Tags: git

I currently have a file structure that looks like this:

```
# C:\Repositories\VisualStudio\MyProject
.git # repository is one level above clientapp and includes other folders/paths than clientapp
afolder
clientapp
file1
file2
```

Now I want to move the `clientapp` folder to a new location and rename it to `frontend`. Then I want to create a new repository only for the `frontend`. No problem until here:

```
# inside C:\Repositories\MyProject\frontend (no more VisualStudio in the path!)
.git
<all the frontend folders and files>
```

Now comes the problem: Of course I now loose the history for the original `clientapp` (now: `frontend`) folder, because I created a new repository. Any way to copy the commits concerning the original `clientapp` folder to my new repository for the `frontend`?

Comment: **See Also**: [Move directory to another repository while keeping the history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41811986/1366033)

Answer (score 13):

**TLDR**: Filter original repository to the folder that one wants to keep, then pull it in from the new repository.

---

1. Download and use [**git-filter-repo**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which `git filter-branch` [officially recommends](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#:%7E:text=Please%20use%20an%20alternative%20history%20filtering%20tool%20such%20as%20git%20filter-repo).

   *Windows Users - see [Install git-filter-repo on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1563034/)
2. Filter repository to relevant files (make sure to have a backup before!):

   ```bash
   git filter-repo --path clientapp
   ```
3. Move the files inside clientapp to the root

   ```bash
   git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter clientapp/
   ```
4. Go to your new repository, add a remote to the original repository:

   ```bash
   git remote add repo-A <path to original repo, e.g. ../repo-A>
   ```
5. Pull files and history from this branch into repository B (containing only the directory you want to move) .

   ```bash
   git pull repo-A master
   ```
6. Remove the remote connection to repository A.

   ```bash
   git remote rm repo-A
   ```
7. Push from your new repository

   ```bash
   git push
   ```
8. Delete the copy of your original repository (that only contains the filtered folder). If needed, clone it again. Happily work with your new repository with a full commit history.

**Further Reading**: Medium article on how to [move files from one repository to another, preserving git history](https://medium.com/@ayushya/git-d210fa049d4b), especially the section on *Merge the files into the new repository B*.

Comment: minor addition: if the git repository you want to clone is on the **same machine**, git would not use its default transport protocol to clone the repository and `git filter-repo --path clientapp` would give you this error: `If Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since this does not look like a fresh clone.`. To avoid that, force git to use its default transport protocol even when cloning local repos. You can do that using `git clone --no-local` instead of just `git clone`