# Separating Wordpress theme from system files in a git repository

Tags: wordpress, git, themes

I've been making a Wordpress theme and using git to save progress. My whole Wordpress site is in the git project, and I would like to remove everything except the theme folder so I can easily transplant it on other Wordpress sites.

I know one way is to just delete everything and move the theme to the root folder and commit. But checking out after that will be more complicated, right? So is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: Wordpress isn't very good for git use because of the folder structure - the core code is in the root and the stuff you can edit (`wp-content`) is a subfolder. With git you can use a submodule, but in this case your base repo would have to be Wordpress itself and your submodules would have to be your plugins/themes, which is hardly ideal in terms of maintenance.

Comment: @jraede I don't understand why. I just want the theme folder as the project. I'll clone it in it's right place within Wordpress installations. What difference do the other files make?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misinterpreted what you were asking. You're going to want to make your theme folder its own git repo, remove it from your project, and then re-add it as a submodule. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871282/nested-git-repositories

Comment: But why keep the Wordpress files in a repo at all? They are not being edited. Seems like it would make deployment a bit more complicated.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [wordpress.se], not sure `:/`

Comment: Definitely not exclusively a Wordpress issue. More to do with git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in keeping the full history of your Theme folder, you can use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) and remove everything else.

See "[Extract part of a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538259/6309)" ,to be done in a clone of your current repo:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter Project/SubProject-0 --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: This seemed to work but somehow the files came back. The files from /wordpress/themes/mytheme are now in /wordpress, but so are all the other files originally there. I don't know how this happened because I don't remembering pulling or cloning.

Comment: @Noah they should be re-generated  by a process which isn't related to Git, but related to WordPress management.

Comment: I don't see how. If there is not wordpress there, how can it manage itself?

Comment: @Noah if you clone that repo again, would those files be part of the clone?

Comment: Looking at my commits with Gitlist, it doesn't show me adding those files back. Cloning just gets the theme files as intended. Maybe this is related to Dropbox?

Comment: @Noah maybe: using Git with Dropbox is generally *not* a good idea. (as in, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)

Comment: I've used Time Machine to revert the changes. They happened between 1AM last night and now. I'll Dropbox-proof my dev folder now. Thanks, VonC.